# ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'slug Django using reverse

Tags: python, django, django-models, reverse, slug

I want to use reverse in the model to back a URL, which has three slugs.
But it gives me an error.

my URL is like this:
site.com/category/slug/slug/slug ...>

- **site.com/category/mobile/nokia/n95**

---

**Error:**

**'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'slug'**

**Model:**

```py
from Django.db import models
from Django.shortcuts import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    child_category = models.ForeignKey('self', max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:brands', args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(to=Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', 'available',)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_details', self.category.model.slug, self.category.model.child_category.slug, self.slug)
```

**URL:**

```py
from Django.urls import path
from Shop import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:brands_slug>/', views.brands, name='brands'),
    path('<slug:brands_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('<slug:brands_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/<slug:product_details>/', views.details_products, name='product_details'),
]
```

**View:**

```py
def details_products(request, brands_slug, product_slug, product_details):
    details = Product.objects.filter(category__child_category__slug=brands_slug, category__slug=product_slug, slug=product_details)
    context = {'details': details}
    return render(request, 'shop/product_details.html', context=context)
```

Comment: change __slug to _slug

Comment: @iklinac: can you tell me more specifically.

Answer (score -1):

change your path to this.

```
path('category/<slug:brands_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/<slug:product_details>/', views.details_products, name='product_details'),
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the category is in the main URL path.

Comment: You know, I think the problem is in reverse at the product model. Something there need to change. The way I use slug for the category it is not right.